# Lotus Domino: vertical scroll bar for view on web

Tags: view, scrollbar, lotus-domino

There is a frameset which contains 2 frames: 1st frame contains an oultine and the 2nd frame contains a view.

The view is listing >8000 documents but even so the vertical scrollbar isn't showing. I also tried checking allow scrollbar at the frame properties, but no results.

Any ideas? I appreciate your time.

PS: I did created a `$$ViewTemplateDefault` containing a text field `$$ViewBody`. But, still, the vertical scroll bar doesn't appear even if it is needed. I read something about adding `overflow` in the `$$ViewBody` field but I don't know exactly how.

Answer (score 0):

In the frameset, Goto the frame properties for the 2nd frame and in the 2nd tab(Frame size) of the properties, you can see the attribute called "Scrolling". Make it "On" or "Default". It will work.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did check it to <ON>, but the scrollbar which appear is not listing all docs, when it is scrolled, only let say 15-20 docs ( when the scrollbar is at topdown of window ) from 250 docs.

Comment: In Notes Client, from the framesets view, Give Ctrl+A to check the no. of docs currently in the view.

Comment: I have 8.264docs which I should see on the web too, using the scroll bar,no? On the top of the view I get 2 buttons: Previous and Next? Is this the only way to see all the docs? By clicking Next or Previous?

Comment: Working on notes client or in Web. If it is web and you have used the the view directly in the frame without $$ViewTemplate then you look at the pagers in the top and bottom of the view.

Comment: I did create a form called $$ViewTemplate with a text field: $$Viewbody. Now, the Previous, Next, Search buttons disappeared, but the scrollbar still not showing. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please go through the following links to create $$ ViewTemplate and If I have answered your question for scroll bar, please make this answer as correct answer.http://www.dominoguru.com/pages/04012009092353.html
http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/04022009083327AMWEBGQY.htm

Comment: I did read the documentations above, I created the form but still the scrollbar doesn't appear!

Comment: Are you aware that there's are server-wide settings for the default number of lines and maximum number of lines rendered in any web view?  http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.help.domino.admin.doc%2FDOC%2Fh_Specifying_the_number_of_lines_to_display_in_the_view.html

Comment: No, i didn't know this fact. Thanks for the info, I will ask the Admin to make these changes and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

overflow is a css property. you could try to add it at the $$ViewBody field, html tab, style, enter overflow:scroll

Why don't you do this view in xpages? do all the 8000 docs show or just around 30? As far as I know there's a server setting which defaults to 30 entries for a view

Comment: I did add overflow property at the style of the field, but no results. I will change the default number of lines in the view.

Comment: By the way: Can't you change to XPages?

Comment: Thanks for your help, @Umeli. I did read the IBM help and the number of lines it reffers to a particular URL , so not my case. I will delete this post.